# Select , character after PRIMARY KEY (`role_id`)

Tags: regex, string

What Regex can select the comma at the end of a line containing

```
PRIMARY KEY ('thisisdifferentbetweeneachline'),
```

I have tried `/PRIMARY\sKEY\s\(.*\),/` but that only selects the entire string and not just the preceding comma.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Why you want to select one character that you know what is it?

Comment: I need to select the comma so I can replace it with "ON UPDATE CASCADE," but only after a line containing "PRIMARY KEY".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for down-voting my question but not giving any feedback.

Regardless the solution that I found after many hours of experimenting and researching was to use capture groups.

The regex to select the first part was /(PRIMARY\sKEY\s(.*))(,)/
so that $1 was "PRIMARY KEY ('thisisdifferentbetweeneachline')" and $2 was ",".

This allowed me to do replace all in my text editor with the Regex /$1 ON UPDATE CASCADE,/

Anyone looking for a similar solution should try looking up capture groups instead of lookahead/lookbehind.